# How to log a python MemoryError (when I'm out of memory)

Tags: python, memory, logging, exception, out-of-memory

**As part of** one of my programs, I want to catch any `MemoryError` and log them.  Currently, I'm using `traceback.format_exception` to format all other exceptions; I would like to do that for `MemoryError` as well.

**However**, using `format_exception` requires using more memory, which is exactly what I cannot do when I'm out of memory.

**What do?**

What can I do when I'm thrown a `MemoryError` besides terminating?  Ideally, I would log them and then resume the program on the assumption that freeing the part of the stack between the handler and the thrower* has freed up sufficient memory for me to do so.

(* and also those heap objects kept alive only by the references emanating from that stack section)

Answer (score 4):

It really has little to do with "the stack".  Python raises `MemoryError` when the system `malloc()` (or similar platform function) returns `NULL`.  In that case, no new memory is actually allocated!  So you have just as much free memory remaining as you did before the request that triggered `MemoryError`.  For example, in an interactive shell on a 32-bit box here:

```
>>> x = [None] * 10**9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
>>>
```

That's harmless.  Yes, in a realistic program, other memory may be freed as the stack unwinds.

But there must be something unusual about your program if "just continuing" won't just lead to another `MemoryError` when the same (or similar) task is attempted again.  The sanest thing is indeed usually exiting the program and starting over again.

@FredMitchell's idea of reserving some "emergency memory" may be worth pursuing.  E.g.,

```
emergency = 'x' * 10**7
```

consumes about 10 MB (in Python 2), mostly in "one big chunk", and your handler could do

```
emergency = ""
```

to release that back to the system.  Then `malloc()` would have a new contiguous block of 10MB to work with.

But, in the end, I bet it will prove a lot easier to just quit ;-)

Comment: Nice! I was thinking of python not being able to explicitly free memory. I should have thought about freeing it "pythonically". :)

Comment: I don't think it's *that* unusual: client data sets of different sizes reside externally; pulling some but not others into memory may prove impossible.  Since the data sets of different clients are isolated, logging and then continuing with the next client's data set makes perfect sense to me.

Also, it's a daemon program I'm talking about, and I don't want to have a guy sit there and rerun it all day.

Comment: @JonasKölker, you didn't say any of that in your original question ;-) For long-running server processes, it's common to have another program running to monitor them, and restart them if they die for *any* reason. Indeed, high-availability servers (like Apache) are designed to periodically kill worker processes and restart them even if nothing goes wrong - this guards against things like slowing performance due to the OS leaking resources, and increasing memory fragmentation, over time. No need to "have a guy sit there" ;-)  There's no way to *guess* whether a `MemoryError` is fatal or benign.

Answer (score 2):

**The recipe** we ended up using:

```
def do_a_generic_memory_hungry_thing(specific_context):
    memory_error = MemoryError(str(specific_context)) # pre-allocate it
    try: memory_hungry_stuff()
    except MemoryError: raise memory_error
```

As it turns out, the trace between `memory_hungry_stuff` and `except` isn't interesting; the interesting part is `specific_context`, so doing the pre-allocation is a twofer in this case.

**Note**: we have run into memory errors trying to print (really: format) `memory_error`, so this isn't bullet proof.  Perhaps combined with releasing a dud string it'll do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In general, an out of memory error is likely to be the toughest problem to deal with in your program since you are out of the main resource that would let you do anything. Perhaps the program could be run in a script that detects the failure from the output and logs it.

You *could* try using some memory whose sole purpose is to be "released" on an out of memory error. But I am not sanguine about that approach in python.